# How do I show all indicators for carousel in an ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, carousel, bootstrap-carousel

I have several slides and I'm able to show all indicators if I simply enumerated them similar to the example in here: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp.

However, the number of slides is dynamic that's why I am using ng-repeat. I'm trying to show all the indicators in my carousel but it only shows 1 indicator for the active slide.

[image]

Here's the HTML of my AngularJS directive.

```
<div class="container slide" id="myCarousel" data-interval="{{carouselVM.interval }}" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators" ng-repeat="curItem in carouselVM.data">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="$index" ng-class="{'active': $index == 0}"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item" style="background-image: url(&quot;{{curItem.image}}&quot;);" ng-repeat="curItem in carouselVM.data" ng-class="{'active' : !$index}">
            <div class="item-headline" ng-bind-html="curItem.description">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left switch-button" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left fa fa-angle-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right switch-button" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right fa fa-angle-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a><br>
</div>
```

How do I show all indicators on every slide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what I need. The `ng-repeat` needs to happen in the `<li>` not the `<ol>`.

```
<div class="container slide" id="myCarousel" data-interval="{{carouselVM.interval }}" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="$index" ng-class="{'active': $index == 0}" ng-repeat="curItem in carouselVM.data"> </li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item" style="background-image: url(&quot;{{curItem.image}}&quot;);" ng-repeat="curItem in carouselVM.data" ng-class="{'active' : !$index}">
            <div class="item-headline" ng-bind-html="curItem.description">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left switch-button" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left fa fa-angle-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right switch-button" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right fa fa-angle-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a><br>
</div>
```